# Swift: Stacking subviews dynamically inside a superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a login in page that is supposed to look like the one listed below. The code I have written should produce this view minus the logo and minus [Login|Register] toggle button. The height and width of my box is also different, but I'm not concerned about that.

[image]

Currently I am getting this output. I'm concerned about how the words are all overlapping each other at the top.

[image]

In the code I listed below I create my 3 text fields, my button and the container for my text fields. I believe there is something wrong in the function fieldConstraints. In this function I look through an array of all my text fields and assign the neccessary constraints to them. They all get the same constraints except that the topAnchor of each text field after the first one is set equal to the bottomAnchor of the separator that was placed underneath the text field before. Those blue lines in between the text fields are the separators.

**Main class**

```
class SignIn: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let inputContainer = inputDataContainer()
        constraintsToCenterSubview(forView: inputContainer, width: 100, height: 100)
        let nameField = field(for: "Name")
        let emailField = field(for: "Email address")
        let passField = field(for: "Password")
        let fields = [nameField, emailField, passField]
        let button = loginButton()
        fieldConstraints(subviews: fields, superview: inputContainer)
        self.centerViewBelow(forView: button, whichIsBelow: inputContainer, increaseWidthBy: 0)
    }

    func inputDataContainer() -> UIView{
        let inputView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y, width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(100)))
        inputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        inputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        inputView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        inputView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.view.addSubview(inputView)
        //inputView = centerViewBelow(forView: inputView, whichIsBelow: self.view, increaseWidthBy: 100)
        return inputView
    }

    func loginButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161)
        button.setTitle("Submit", for: [])
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: [])
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        return button
    }

    func field(for name: String) -> UITextField{
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = name
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(tf)
        return tf
    }

    func fieldSep() -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }

    func fieldConstraints(subviews: [UIView], superview: UIView) {
        var sep: UIView?
        let len = subviews.endIndex
        for (idx, subview) in subviews.enumerated(){
            superview.addSubview(subview)
            subview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leftAnchor)
            subview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.rightAnchor)
            subview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor)
            subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.heightAnchor, multiplier: CGFloat(1/len))
            if (sep != nil){
                subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sep!.bottomAnchor)
            }else{
                subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor)
            }
            sep = fieldSep()
            if idx < subviews.endIndex-1 {
                self.view.addSubview(sep!)
                sep?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leftAnchor)
                sep?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.rightAnchor)
                sep?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.bottomAnchor)
            }
        }


    }
}
```

**Extensions**

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(r:CGFloat, g:CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func centerViewBelow(forView view: UIView, whichIsBelow topView: UIView, increaseWidthBy constant: CGFloat){
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: constant)
        let centerConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint, widthConstraint, centerConstraint, heightConstraint])
        //return view
    }

    func constraintsToCenterSubview(forView view: UIView, width: Int, height: Int){
        let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(width))
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(height))
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
    }

}
```

Thank you

---

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

**Update**

So I was pretty much able to do it by changing my container into a stack view. But this made it so that my corners were no longer rounded. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
func inputDataContainer() -> UIStackView{
    let inputView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y, width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(100)))
    inputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    inputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    inputView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    inputView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    inputView.distribution = .fillEqually
    inputView.axis = .vertical
    inputView.spacing = 1
    self.view.addSubview(inputView)
    //inputView = centerViewBelow(forView: inputView, whichIsBelow: self.view, increaseWidthBy: 100)
    return inputView
}

func fieldConstraints(subviews: [UIView], superview: UIStackView) {
    for subview in subviews{
        superview.addArrangedSubview(subview)
        subview.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

**Example Screen Shot of Current App**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to give height for

```
sep?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:1.0).isActive = true
```

also for all constraints in `fieldConstraints` you forget

```
.isActive = true
```

or use `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` , like

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
     subview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leftAnchor),
     subview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.rightAnchor)  
     subview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor),
     subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.heightAnchor, multiplier: CGFloat(1/len))
])
```

This approach will work but it will be better to use a vertical stackview with distribution `.fillEqually` and it'll will partition them and add like

```
 fileds.forEach { stackview.addArrangedSubview($0) }
```

Comment: The answer you gave made sense, but I'm not sure what you meant with that comment at the end. Where do I input '.fillequally'

Comment: So I couldn't get it working by the code you posted, but I looked up UIStackView and was pretty much able to do it, except the corners are no longer rounded. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: you cas't round a stackview , you need to round the most top and bottom textfields

Answer (score 0):

use `UIStackView`. it will help you save time to build a complicated UI.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a little trouble using a `UIStackView`. You could embed it in a `UIView` and give that view the rounded corners, but then you have to add padding to the fields *within* the stack view in order to get your separator lines.

Here is another approach that might work better for you. It's closer to your original code, adding the fields and separator views to a `UIView`:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(r:CGFloat, g:CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}

class SampleViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 65, g: 92, b: 144)

        let nameField = field(for: "Name")
        let sep1 = fieldSep()
        let emailField = field(for: "Email address")
        let sep2 = fieldSep()
        let passField = field(for: "Password")
        let views = [nameField, sep1, emailField, sep2, passField]
        let inputView = inputDataContainer(with: views)

        view.addSubview(inputView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            inputView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            inputView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            inputView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

    }

    func field(for s: String) -> UITextField {
        let f = UITextField()
        f.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        f.placeholder = s
        f.borderStyle = .none
        return f
    }

    func fieldSep() -> UIView {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0).isActive = true
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        return v
    }

    func inputDataContainer(with subviews: [UIView]) -> UIView {

        let horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 8.0
        let verticalSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0

        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        var previousView: UIView?

        for subview in subviews{
            containerView.addSubview(subview)

            // if it's a text field, we want padding on left and right
            if subview is UITextField {
                subview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: horizontalPadding).isActive = true
                subview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -horizontalPadding).isActive = true
            } else {
                subview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
                subview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            }

            if subview == subviews.first {
                // if it's the first subview, constrain to top of container
                subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: verticalSpacing).isActive = true
            } else {
                // unwrap previousView and constrain subview to bottom of previous subview
                if let pv = previousView {
                    subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pv.bottomAnchor, constant: verticalSpacing).isActive = true
                }
            }
            if subview == subviews.last {
                // if it's the last subview, constrain to bottom of container
                subview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -verticalSpacing).isActive = true
            }

            // save reference to current subview
            previousView = subview

        }

        return containerView
    }

}
```

And the result:

[image]